# Macro doesn't run when data is refreshed?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code to detect the change in value of a cell and then run a macro, but when the data is refreshed due to data connection the code doesn't work.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Address = "$A$2" Then

If target.Value = 1 Then

taskID = Shell("c:\imawesome.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    End If
    If target.Value = 0 Then

taskID = Shell("c:\Sender.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The code only works when I manually enter the data in a cell.
Please suggest the code which runs when the data is refreshed.

Comment: This KB article from Microsoft may be helpfull [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213187)

Comment: @Ateszki +1. You should post this as an answer (presuming that the data connection is a query table)

Answer (score 1):

Following this microsoft article [KB213187](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213187) and assuming your data connection is a querytable

You can try this

create a new module and put this code in it

```
Public WithEvents qt As QueryTable

Private Sub qt_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)

  'do your stuff here

End Sub
```

then on another module create a class

```
Dim X As New Class1

Sub Initialize_It()
  Set X.qt = Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).QueryTables(1)
End Sub
```

And make sure the Initialize_It runs every time you open the document.

Be aware that this code works for only one qquerytable per document, modifications are needed if you have more.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the worksheet_change won't fire, try using the worksheet_calculate event. It executes when any cell calculates, so you can put in a test in for your desired cell and (previous) value.

Comment: private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("A1")

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    If target.Value = 1 Then

taskID = Shell("c:\imawesome.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    End If
    If target.Value = 0 Then

taskID = Shell("c:\Sender.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    End If

    End If
End Sub Its not working at all on refreshing too.